Get rid of irrationality in the denominator $\frac{9-40\sqrt[3]{6}-6\sqrt[3]{36}}{1-\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36}}$

Get rid of irrationality in the denominator
$$\cfrac{9-40\sqrt[3]{6}-6\sqrt[3]{36}}{1-\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36}}$$

$$\left ( 1-\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )\left ( 1+\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )=\left ( 1-\left ( \sqrt[3]{6}+3\sqrt[3]{36} \right ) \right )\left ( 1+\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )=$$
$$=1+\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36}-\left ( \sqrt[3]{6}+3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )-\left ( \sqrt[3]{6}+3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )\left ( \sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )=$$
$$=1+\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36}-\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36}-\sqrt[3]{36}+54\sqrt[3]{6}=1+54\sqrt[3]{6}-7\sqrt[3]{36}$$
This is how I converted the denominator and got the following fraction
$$\cfrac{9-40\sqrt[3]{6}-6\sqrt[3]{36}}{1+54\sqrt[3]{6}-7\sqrt[3]{36}}\cdot \left ( 1+\sqrt[3]{6}-3\sqrt[3]{36} \right )$$
It seems I approached the task incorrectly. What do you need to multiply the denominator by to get rid of irrationality? Is there an efficient way to simplify a given fraction without calculators?

Try to multiply with $1+a\sqrt[3]{6}+b\sqrt[3]{36}$, and then choose $a$ and $b$ correctly.

It might help to let $x = 6^{1/3}$ and write the denominator as
$$q(x) = 1 - x - 3x^2.$$  Then we want to find a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x)q(x) = g(x^3)$ for some polynomial $g$.  Let's try a general form of degree $2$, i.e.
$$f(x) = c + bx + ax^2.$$
Note we may take $c = 1$ without loss of generality.  So we have
$$f(x)q(x) = (1-x-3x^2)(1+bx+ax^2) = 1 + (b-1)x + (a-b-3)x^2 - (a+3b)x^3 - 3ax^4.$$
Since $x^3 = 6$, we have $x^4 = 6x$, and we can rewrite this as
$$f(x)q(x) = 1 + (-18a+b-1)x + (a-b-3)x^2 - (a+3b)x^3.$$
Hence we require
$$\begin{align}
-18a + b - 1 &= 0 \\
a-b-3 &= 0
\end{align}$$
to simultaneously hold.  What is the solution?

Question, could you show how we can transform the numerator after we have gotten rid of the irrationality in the denominators?

@Dmitry $$(9-40x-6x^2)(1+bx+ax^2) = 9 + (9b-40)x + (9a-40b-6)x^2 - (40a+6b)x^3 - 6ax^4.$$  Now let $x^3 = 6$ and $x^4 = 6x$, substitute the values of $a$ and $b$ you calculated, and simplify.

Setting $x:=\sqrt[3]{6}$ we require that $(1-x-3x^2)(1+ax+bx^2)\in \Bbb Q$. Since $x^3=6$ this is equivalent to $a-b+3=0$ and $a-18b-1=0$. This yields $a=-\frac{55}{17}$ and $b=-\frac{4}{17}$. Then the denominator becomes $\frac{1031}{17}$.
